# Jenkins Pipeline Stage View

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have three stages and due to some error when my build fails the Jenkins pipeline stage view is as shown below -

[image]

Now I am trying to fail the build if certain conditions are not met in one of the stage. But when I am doing that then instead of showing that particular stage in **Red color** all the subsequent stages are also shown in Red and with a failed tag at the bottom left corner. PFB the related screenshot

[image]

As shown in the **first** image, this behavior is not observed when build fails due to some error.Only the stage where error occurred is in Red with a failed tag at bottom-left corner. All the subsequent Stages are in White color.

I am using the following script inside Second Stage:

```
steps{if(condition not met){error("Build failed because of this and that..")}}
```

How to achieve the same view as that of First image when we are Failing the Build on the basis of some condition?

Answer (score 1):

Posibly you need to upgrade your Jenkins.

I am in version `Jenkins ver. 2.204.2` and for me it shows clearly the failure of a particular stage and doesnt show all to be RED.[image]